I'm creating a dashboard using shiny. The select bar of one of my graphics limts the number of choices
With the function pickerInput from shiny widgets I created the select bar. There are twelve options in the in-choice argument but only the eight first show up. In the options, I set 'action-box' to TRUE. I also set the style like this:
style = "height: 700px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; overflow-y: auto",
                  div(
                    style = "height: 15%; display: flex; align-items: center;",
                    HTML("<b style='font-size:19px'> Title </b>")
                  ),

Has anyone had this problem before?
I tried setting the argument size in the options to number 12, but didn't work. It only took off the screen of the select bar, showing fewer options from choice.

We are going to need to see a lot more of your code to be able to help - please post the code for a complete shiny app that anyone can copy and run
